# как мне установить Tensorflow через pip

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

как мне установить Tensorflow через pip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информация с [tensorflow.org:](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
# Verify install:
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Comment: raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. не работает!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Stepan, странно, но у меня установка прошла успешно. Попробуй увеличить время ожидания `pip --default-timeout=100 install tensorflow `